# How can I use this dataset "MC1" to plot a KNN decision boundary figure?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

How can I use this dataset "MC1" to plot a KNN decision boundary figure?
Here is my code, I have tried to use iloc and loc but did not work

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from yellowbrick.contrib.classifier import DecisionViz
from yellowbrick.features import RadViz
from yellowbrick.style import set_palette
set_palette('flatui')

data_set = pd.read_csv('MC1.csv')

X, y = data_set
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tts(X, y, test_size=.4, random_state=42)
visualizer = RadViz(size=(500, 400))
viz = DecisionViz(
    KNeighborsClassifier(5), title="Nearest Neighbors",classes=['Y', 'N']
)

viz.fit(X_train, y_train)
viz.draw(X_test, y_test)
viz.show()
```

Comment: You should make it clear that you are asking about the `yellowbrick` library by adding the corresponding tag.  Also, instead of simply saying "it did not work", please be specific and describe the result of your current code (including posting any exception traceback output) and your expected result.  You can [edit] the question.

Comment: Also, `X, y = data_set` is probably not what you wanted to do, as you are simply assigning the full dataframe to two new variables.  You will need to explicitly specify which columns are to be assigned to `X` and which ones to `y`.

Comment: @AlexK okay!! can u write a code then?
I'm new to this library and just started.